# Visual studio 2015 showing 'Debug is Starting'

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I have visual studio 2015, and it suddenly stopped working. When I run application in it, it is showing process of "Debug is starting", but nothing is happening.
[image]

Comment: Probably visual studio is waiting to establish a connection with IIS Express, but IIS doesn't responds.
Can you check if IIS Express is running?

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti IIS express is running in tray. My other projects are also running. Only problem with one this project. Is there something in project properties, needs to be changed?

Comment: You'll probably need to stop or kill IIS Express, shutdown VS2015, then stop all of the *other* VS processes, such as VsHub.exe.  Now that VS2015 has some of its features handled out of process, you'll want to find these out from running Process Explorer.  Sometimes VS2015 just gets stuck.

Comment: @ChrisO I didi everything, even restarted PC, but no luck. My other types of projects are working fine in VS2015, only problem with this project. Is it related to something .Net core?

Comment: Can you start your project without debug?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to clean your project before start.
2. You can try to run your peoject without debugging, but then you can
   attach the debugger to your aplpication [image: Debug Menu]

Answer (score 0):

This started for me when I unchecked 'Enable Anonymous Authentication' on the Debug page of the project's settings. Re-enabling this allowed Debugging to start correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to restart Visual Studio and it worked for me.